# align forall to the right hand side

Tags: equations, align

I have a few equations, and I would like to align the *forall* statements of these equations to the right-hand side as below:
[image]

However, when I add a new equation (eq19), I have no idea why I cannot get a result as above. Would you please help me to resolve this problem using a similar notation as above (since I do not want to change all equations in my main file)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
  & o_{cs} \leq mO 
  & \forall c \in \mathcal{C}; s \in \mathcal{S} \label{eq18}\\
%   & a_{jcs} - a_{jbs} \geq 
%     (\sum_{i \in \mathcal{T} \cup \alpha} 
%      x_{ijcs} + 
%      \sum_{i \in \mathcal{T} \cup \alpha} 
%      x_{ijbs} - 2)\Omega \nonumber \\
%   & 
%   & \forall j \in \mathcal{T}; b, c \in \mathcal{C}; s \in \mathcal{S}; NC_{js} > 1 \label{eq19}\\
  & \sum_{i \in \mathcal{T} \cup \alpha}
    \sum_{j \in \mathcal{T}}
    x_{ijcs} \: T_{js} \leq (ES_s-BS_s) \: {fR_c} 
  & \forall c \in \mathcal{C}; s \in \mathcal{S} \label{eq19a}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your longest left aligned equation + longest right aligned equation + number will be wider than your total available width.

Here, the equations will fit:

[image]

But as soon as you add the `\in` or more to the right hand equation, the total width will be overfull and the `flalign` environment won't be able to section it up into two good boxes and thereby can't have the equations and numbering on the same line:

[image]

Thereby you either have to use another environment than `flalign` or widen the text width using the `geometry` package.

```
\usepackage{geometry}
```

Which will adjust the widths for your case to work, but the widths of the page can still be set manually with the `geometry` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
  % Line 1
  & o_{cs} \leq mO 
  & \forall c \in \mathcal{C}; s \in \mathcal{S} \label{eq18}\\
  % Line 2
  & a_{jcs} - a_{jbs} \geq 
    (\sum_{i \in \mathcal{T} \cup \alpha} 
     x_{ijcs} + 
     \sum_{i \in \mathcal{T} \cup \alpha} 
     x_{ijbs} - 2)\Omega
  & \forall j \in \mathcal{T}; b, c \in \mathcal{C}; s \in \mathcal{S}; NC_{js} > 1 \label{eq19}\\
  % Line 3
  & \sum_{i \in \mathcal{T} \cup \alpha}
    \sum_{j \in \mathcal{T}}
    x_{ijcs} \: T_{js} \leq (ES_s-BS_s) \: {fR_c} 
  & \forall c \in \mathcal{C}; s \in \mathcal{S} \label{eq19a}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}  % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \smashoperator macro

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
  & o_{cs} \leq mO 
  & \forall c \in \mathcal{C}; s \in \mathcal{S} \tag{18}\\
  & a_{jcs} - a_{jbs} \geq \Bigl(\, 
     \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{i \in \mathcal{T} \cup \alpha}} x_{ijcs} + 
     \smashoperator{   \sum_{i \in \mathcal{T} \cup \alpha}} x_{ijbs} 
      - 2\Bigr)\Omega 
  & \forall j \in \mathcal{T}; b, c \in \mathcal{C}; s \in \mathcal{S}; NC_{js} > 1 \tag{19}\\
  & \smashoperator[l]{\sum_{i \in \mathcal{T} \cup \alpha}} \,
    \smashoperator{\sum_{j \in \mathcal{T}}}
    x_{ijcs} \, T_{js} \leq (ES_s-BS_s) \, fR_c
  & \forall c \in \mathcal{C}; s \in \mathcal{S} \tag{19a}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is strange :-( but seem that the first \Bigl(\, it is a bit more great of the \Bigr) before the -2. Maybe it's just an impression. I would put a \setcounter from 17 and a subequation instead of the tags.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Thanks. Indeed, the proximity of "large" and "small" stuff near the `\Big` parentheses seems to influence the visual perception of the height of the parentheses.