# alignment of 'forall' for long equations

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, forall

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610949/align-forall-to-the-right-hand-side) provides a solution for aligning equations to the right-hand side. Apparently, it does not work when equations are long. Assuming a given width, how should I modify the following equation to achieve an alignment like the one in the older post?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
    & p^{'w}_{koi0} = \theta_{koi} 
    & \forall k \in \mathcal{K}; o \in \mathcal{O}; i \in \mathcal{I}_k \label{eqTP0}\\
    & p^{'w}_{koie} = p^w_{koi(e-1)} - 
                     \sum_{\substack{t \in \mathcal{T} \\ t \ge AV_{ko}}}
                     \sum_{\substack{c \in \mathcal{C} \\ \sum_{b \in \mathcal{B}_c} G_{kb} > 0}}
                     z^1_{koi(e-1)tc} - 
                     \zeta_{koi(e-1)} + 
                     \sum_{\substack{i' \in \mathcal{I}_k\\ i' = i+1}} 
                     \zeta_{koi'(e-1)} & \nonumber \\
    & & \forall k \in \mathcal{K}; o \in \mathcal{O}; i \in \mathcal{I}_k; e \in \mathcal{E}_k; e > 0 \label{eqTP1}\\
    & \zeta_{koie} \leq p^w_{koie} - 
                        \sum_{\substack{t \in \mathcal{T} \\ t \ge AV_{ko}}}
                        \sum_{\substack{c \in \mathcal{C} \\ \sum_{b \in \mathcal{B}_c} G_{kb} > 0}}
                        z^1_{koietc}
    & \forall k \in \mathcal{K}; o \in \mathcal{O}; i \in \mathcal{I}_k; e \in \mathcal{E}_k; e > 0 \label{eqTP2}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

My current code produces the following result:

[image]

Comment: It should be `p'^{w}`, not `p^{'w}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can hide the width with negative space

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
    & p'^{w}_{koi0} = \theta_{koi} 
    & \forall k \in \mathcal{K}; o \in \mathcal{O}; i \in \mathcal{I}_k \label{eqTP0}\\[4pt]
    & p'^{w}_{koie} = p^w_{koi(e-1)} - 
                     \sum_{\substack{t \in \mathcal{T} \\ t \ge AV_{ko}}}
                     \sum_{\substack{c \in \mathcal{C} \\ \sum_{b \in \mathcal{B}_c} G_{kb} > 0}}
                     z^1_{koi(e-1)tc} - 
                     \zeta_{koi(e-1)} + 
                     \sum_{\substack{i' \in \mathcal{I}_k\\ i' = i+1}} 
                     \zeta_{koi'(e-1)}\hspace{-\textwidth} & \nonumber \\
    & & \forall k \in \mathcal{K}; o \in \mathcal{O}; i \in \mathcal{I}_k; e \in \mathcal{E}_k; e > 0 \label{eqTP1}\\[4pt]
    & \zeta_{koie} \leq p^w_{koie} - 
                        \sum_{\substack{t \in \mathcal{T} \\ t \ge AV_{ko}}}
                        \sum_{\substack{c \in \mathcal{C} \\ \sum_{b \in \mathcal{B}_c} G_{kb} > 0}}
                        z^1_{koietc}
    & \forall k \in \mathcal{K}; o \in \mathcal{O}; i \in \mathcal{I}_k; e \in \mathcal{E}_k; e > 0 \label{eqTP2}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

I also avoided the double supercript prime, `p'^{w}` not `p^{'w}`